# code does not list all even numbers between two inputs

Tags: bash

I have this bash script and when you enter two integers the for loop is supposed to list all the even numbers between the two integers. I have recently been having trouble with the for loop, when I enter for instance 2 and 10, it starts listing even numbers 4 6 8 without listing 2 and 10 as well e.g. 2 4 6 8 10. I have tried to fix it but have had no luck, would anyone be able to help?

```
if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then

        for((i=($1+($1%2));i<($2-3);i+=2));do  #for loop lists all even numbers

        if (( i %  7 == 0 )); then #checks if even number divisible by 7
                echo " $i : x " # 
                elif (( $i % 11 == 0 )); then #else if checks if divisible by 7
                        echo " $i : y " 
                        elif (( $i % 13 == 0 )); then  #if divisible by 13
                                echo " $i : z " #prints number 
                        fi   #closes the if statement
                        printf "%d%s, " "$i"
                        done


elif [ $# -eq 0 ]; then   #checks if number of arguments is 0                                                                                             
        read -p "Please input starting and ending integer" val1 val2  #prints error message
        for((i=($val1+($val1%2));i<($val2-3);i+=2));do
                if (( i % 7 == 0 )); then
                        echo "$i : x "
                        elif (( $i % 11 == 0 )); then
                                echo " $i : y"
                                elif (( $i % 13 == 0 )); then
                                        echo " $i : x "
                                fi
                                printf "%d%s, " "$i"
                                done
```

Comment: First add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: You can simplify this code by just setting `val1=$1` and `val2=$2`  in the `if` statement when feasible. Then you can use a *single* `for` loop *after* the `if` statement completes.

Comment: @chepner its part of a task I'm doing so its a requirement, btw its fairly new to the bash script coding, would you be able to show me how I can use the thing you mentioned above ?

Comment: @chepner following your comment about no even numbers being divisible by 7 and 11, 14 and 22 are two examples of even numbers that are divisible by 7 or 11.

Comment: Let's just forget I said that... <facepalm/>

Comment: btw thanks so much for the help you provided, it was amazing and I have definitely learnt something new. All the best

Answer (score 1):

The primary issue appears to be your subtraction of 3 from the upper endpoint, which would account for 10 missing. I don't see how your code wouldn't output 2 in the first place, though.

You only need one `for` loop, though, with appropriately initialized values for `val1` and `val2`.

```
if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
  val1=$1
  val2=$2
elif [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  read -p "..." val1 val2
else
  exit 1
fi


for ((i=val1 + val1%2; i <= val2; i+=2)); do
   ...
done
```